# Kernel panic when trying to setup rootfs over NFS on ARM board

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a ARM board on which I am trying to configure NFS so that the rootfs will be mounted over a network. How can I resolve this?

**My server configuration:**

OS: Scientific Linux 6.0

**My NFS shares:**

```
#cat /etc/exports
/tftpboot/squashfs-root        192.168.1.5(rw,insecure,sync,no_root_squash)

#showmount -e 192.168.1.100
Export list for 192.168.1.100:
/tftpboot/squashfs-root 192.168.1.5
```

**My target settings:**

```
U-Boot> printenv
    bootcmd=sf read 0xa00000 0x30000 0x1d0000;sf read 0x3000000 0x200000 0x800000;jump    0xa00000  
    bootdelay=3  
    baudrate=38400  
    netmask=255.255.0.0  
    modelname=DEVBOARD  
    ethaddr=02:00:11:21:32:45  
    serverip=192.168.1.100  
    gatewayip=192.168.1.10  
    ipaddr=192.168.1.5  
    bootargs=root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.100:/tftpboot/squashfs-root nolock,tcp mem=64M      console=2
```

**Boot log:**

```
NET: Registered protocol family 17  
RPC: Registered udp transport module.  
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.  
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.1.100  
rpcbind: server 192.168.1.100 not responding, timed out  
Root-NFS: Unable to get nfsd port number from server, using default  
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.1.100  
rpcbind: server 192.168.1.100 not responding, timed out  
Root-NFS: Unable to get mountd port number from server, using default  
Root-NFS: Server returned error -5 while mounting /tftpboot/squashfs-root  
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.  
VFS: Cannot open root device "<NULL>" or unknown-block(2,0)  
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:  
1f00             192 mtdblock0 (driver?)  
1f01            1856 mtdblock1 (driver?)  
1f02            8192 mtdblock2 (driver?)  
1f03            6144 mtdblock3 (driver?)  
1f04             256 mtdblock4 (driver?)  
1f05             256 mtdblock5 (driver?)  
1f06            4096 mtdblock6 (driver?)  
1f07           16384 mtdblock7 (driver?)  
1f08           98304 mtdblock8 (driver?)  
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Root-NFS: Unable to get nfsd port number from server, using default

Your NFS server does not run the `portmap` daemon, or the firewall rules do not allow the client to connect to it. Google says the service might be called "rpcbind".